# Proper way to simply play a mp3 sounds as notification

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have some small mp3 files that I want to play as notification sounds in my application. Just to be clear, I have already created a "raw" folder under Resources and added my mp3 files there. As a first pass, I was just using the MediaPlayer like this:

`MediaPlayer mPlayer;`

`mPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(context, Resource.Raw.warning);`

`mPlayer.Start();`

And that worked but it seemed a little clunky when all I want to do is use them as notifications, not for playing audio tracks. I also think there is more overhead with that approach to make sure the player is done playing, disposed, etc...

So, I found the SoundPool and implemented that. There were some early questions, for example, when you load a sound into the SoundPool, it returns an int for the SoundID which you then use later as a reference to the sound you want to play. Therefore, I had to create a separate class to handle those properties as well.

This is what I have so far and it seems to be working but I am wondering if this is the best way still?

First, I created a class to wrap the SoundPool up and it has a class for the SoundID as well.

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;

namespace PocketPacTracAndroid.Media
{
    public class Sounds
    {
        SoundPool soundPool;
        Context context;
        int maxStreams = 1;
        bool isLoaded = false;

    public bool IsLoaded
    {
        get { return isLoaded; }
    }

    public Sounds(Context oContext)
    {
        soundPool = new SoundPool(maxStreams, Stream.Music, 0);
        context = oContext;
        loadSoundPool();
    }

    public Sounds(Context oContext, int streams)
    {
        maxStreams = streams;
        soundPool = new SoundPool(maxStreams, Stream.Music, 0);
        loadSoundPool();
    }

    private void loadSoundPool()
    {
        soundPool.LoadComplete += SoundPool_LoadComplete;
        SoundIDs sid = new SoundIDs();
        sid.Scan = soundPool.Load(context, Resource.Raw.scan, 1);
        sid.PackageAdded = soundPool.Load(context, Resource.Raw.packageAdded, 1);
        sid.HubTransfer = soundPool.Load(context, Resource.Raw.hubtransfer, 1);
        sid.Alert = soundPool.Load(context, Resource.Raw.alert, 1);
        sid.Warning = soundPool.Load(context, Resource.Raw.warning, 1);
        sid.ScanChange = soundPool.Load(context, Resource.Raw.scanchange, 1);
    }

    private void SoundPool_LoadComplete(object sender, SoundPool.LoadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        isLoaded = true;
    }

    public void playSound(int sid)
    {
        if (isLoaded)
        {
            soundPool.Play(sid, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
        }
    }
}

public class SoundIDs
{
    int scan;
    int packageAdded;
    int hubTransfer;
    int alert;
    int warning;
    int scanChange;


    public int Scan
    {
        get { return scan; }
        set { scan = value; }
    }

    public int PackageAdded
    {
        get { return packageAdded; }
        set { packageAdded = value; }
    }

    public int HubTransfer
    {
        get { return hubTransfer; }
        set { hubTransfer = value; }
    }

    public int Alert
    {
        get { return alert; }
        set { alert = value; }
    }

    public int Warning
    {
        get { return warning; }
        set { warning = value; }
    }

    public int ScanChange
    {
        get { return scanChange; }
        set { scanChange = value; }
    }
}
}
```

Then, from anywhere in my app, I instantiate the classes:

```
    Sounds sounds;
    SoundIDs sid;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = Context;
        getServiceTypes();
        sounds = new Sounds(context);
        sid = new SoundIDs();
    }
```

and finally, I can call this to play the sound based on my soundID that was returned when I loaded in the files. I also exposed IsLoaded in case I want to check that externally but it is checked internally when playSound is called.

```
sounds.playSound(sid.Scan);
```

Does this seem like a good approach? Is it the best? Any suggestions would be appreciated. It does seem to work but I just want to make sure I won't have any resource issues or playback issues if I call the same or different notifications over and over again during the application lifecycle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes SoundPool is the way to go.  Just watch out for threads playing different sounds at the same time.  Unless you build in a queue, some sounds will block others as there is only one speaker.